# If the ratio of 2x to 5y is 3 to 4, what's the ratio of x to y?

Tags: linear-algebra, ratio

This is my first post here. I'm trying to recap basic maths and been struggling with ratios. Could you please help me understand the steps to resolve the problem above?

What I tried:

3x/5y = 3/4 --> Then cross multiply it! Not sure if this is correct and my answer book doesn't show methods, only answers. Not correct.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it easily, you need the value of $\dfrac{x}{y}$.

So remove $\dfrac{2}{5}$ form $\dfrac{2x}{5y}$ by multiplying it's reciprocal  $\big(\dfrac{5}{2}\big)$ from both sides.
$$\dfrac{\not5}{\not2}×\dfrac{\not2x}{\not5y}=\dfrac{3}{4}×\dfrac{5}{2}$$
$$\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{15}{8}$$
I hope it' ll help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it looks quite simple and elegant

Comment: @Trentini Thank you so much. If you like my answer then upvote it

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{2x}{5y} = \frac{3}{4}$$

$$ \frac{x}{y} = \ ?$$

Hint: try multiplying both sides by $\frac{5}{2}$